# Wrong last Name on Flight Ticket

Tags: tickets

I have written on my flight ticket from Portugal to Egypt, my first and middle name instead of my last name, like if it’s John Smith Snow, I have written John Smith instead of John Snow. Will it be a problem??

Comment: Most probably, yes. Contact your airline to have this fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it must match your passport. I would contact the company and get this fixed ASAP.